# What do we call below screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, bottom-sheet

Attached screen below is called as BootmSheet with notch ? or there is any specifi c component name for this in UIKIT ?

[image]

Comment: you can add a subview with an animation or present a viewcontroller with a transparent background.

Comment: how to add a top notch ?

Comment: Do you meant the two top round corner for the white view?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a top notch is just a matter of rendering another UIView on top of your `BootmSheet` view.

This is best illustrated in a playground. Try running this code in a playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.view = view
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let dimmedView = UIView()
    dimmedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.65)
    dimmedView.frame = view.bounds
    view.addSubview(dimmedView)

    let roundedView = UIView()
    roundedView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 200, width: 200, height: 25)
    roundedView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    roundedView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMinYCorner]
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    view.addSubview(roundedView)
  }
}


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```